# Why is it bad practice to write "In [1], it is shown that..."

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

I don't remember where, but I read that it is not recommended to write, in a article, something like

> [...], as detailed in [1].

Instead, we should write

> [...], as detailed by Someone [1].

In other words, reference numbers should not be treated as nouns. Why is it so? I see nothing disturbing with the first form.